# Textbox integer validation error

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I want to check that client write integer in my textbox so I write my code like this :

```
<td class="style2">
 <asp:TextBox ID="phonetxt" runat="server" Height="22px" MaxLength="10" 
 Width="158px"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PhoneRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="phonetxt"  ErrorMessage="...."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator6" runat="server" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Accepts only numbers." ControlToValidate="phonetxt" ValidationExpression=""^[0-9]*$" Text="*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</td>
```

But an error occured like this:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.
>   Source Error: 
>   Line 153:                 
>   Line 154:                  
>       Line 155:               
>   Line 156:              
>   Line 157:
>
> Source File: /account.aspx    Line: 155

What shold I do now? Is there any better way for check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
ValidationExpression=""^[0-9]*$"
```

with

```
ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$"
```

Comment: thanks it's working now but it doesn't show any error when I write wrong values!!!! What's the problem?

Comment: a `"` needs to be escaped within text - so you need to write `\"`

Answer (score 0):

Base on the error.
You forget a opening in this

```
asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PhoneRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="phonetxt"  ErrorMessage="...."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

< you are missing this...

As for the  `ValidationExpression=""^[0-9]*$"` 
If you really need to have " put an escape on it so it become

```
ValidationExpression="\"^[0-9]*$"
```